# How can i solve $2x+ \frac{3}{5} =1 $ in $Z_7$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, divisibility

How can I solve: $$2x+ \frac{3}{5} =1 $$ in $Z_7$?

I can check any element from $Z_7$ and get the solution, but I ask for algorithm for questions from this type (that will work for any $Z_n$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
10x+3&=& 5\\
20x+6&=& 10\\
-x-1&=&3 \\
x&=&-4 \\
x&=&3 
\end{eqnarray}

So $x=7k+3$.

Comment: Thank you about your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is no algorythm per se but I would do like this:

$$
2x+\frac{3}{5}\equiv 1 \ (\bmod 7)
$$
$$
10x+3\equiv 5 \ (\bmod 7)
$$
$$
3x\equiv 2 \ (\bmod 7)
$$
$$
15x\equiv 10 \ (\bmod 7)
$$
$$
x\equiv 3 \ (\bmod 7)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$3 \cdot 5 = 15 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$ implies
$\dfrac15 \equiv 3 \bmod 7$ and so $\dfrac35 \equiv 9 \bmod 7$

$2x+9 \equiv 1$ implies $x \equiv -4 \equiv 3 \bmod 7$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, in $\Bbb Z_n$, $a^{\varphi(n)-1}=a^{-1}$ for all $a\in \Bbb Z_n^*$. If $n=p_1^{h_1}\cdots p_m^{h_m}$ is the decomposition into distinct prime factors, then $$\varphi(n)=\left(p_1^{h_1}-p_1^{h_1-1}\right)\left(p_2^{h_2}-p_2^{h_2-1}\right)\cdots\left(p_m^{h_m}-p_m^{h_m-1}\right)=n\frac{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots(p_m-1)}{p_1p_2\cdots p_m}.$$ This should provide you with the tools you need to compute fractions that make sense and to solve equations in the form $ax=b\pmod n$ when $\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)=1$.